# Why does site title does not get updated on Sharepoint admin center if its changed from site settings in case of non English site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

While working on SharePoint, I observed that the behavior of English and non-English sites differs when renaming the site from the site setting.

Observation:

- Non-English Sites: Once you edit the title from site settings, it stops synchronization between site names on the SharePoint admin center and the site title.
- English Sites: No issue observed.

Steps to repro:

- Create a non-English communication site.
- Rename from Admin center => new site name would reflect on site.
- Rename from Site => This would not affect the Admin center's site title.
- Here onwards synchronization between titles is broken.

Is this a known issue? I did not find anything related to this.